# Does Oracle 11g optimize For loops over arrays?

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, oracle11g

Does Oracle 11g optimize For Loops over arrays?
If so how does it do it?

Example:
Does the following code treat each instance of `lt_some_array(i)` as a pointer to the record in the array at index `i`? Or, does it look it up every time?

```
FOR i IN lt_some_array.FIRST..lt_some_array.LAST
LOOP
   field1 := lt_some_array(i).field1;
   field2 := lt_some_array(i).field2;
   field3 := lt_some_array(i).field3;
   field4 := lt_some_array(i).field4;
   field5 := lt_some_array(i).field5;
   field6 := lt_some_array(i).field6;
   do_something();
END LOOP;
```

Clarification:
Does the compiler treat it like the following (where lr_some_row is a pointer and not a copy):

```
FOR i IN lt_some_array.FIRST..lt_some_array.LAST
LOOP
   lr_some_row := lt_some_array(i);
   field1 := lr_some_row.field1;
   field2 := lr_some_row.field2;
   field3 := lr_some_row.field3;
   field4 := lr_some_row.field4;
   field5 := lr_some_row.field5;
   field6 := lr_some_row.field6;
   do_something();
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Why you would do such a thing, I don't know but it acts as a pointer. You can test it by trying the lookups and seeing the difference

Comment: The array (or collection) is expected to already have data on it so `array_name(i).field1` would be a pointer to the i'th index of the array and field `field1`. Also, can  you be more precise when you say optimize?

Comment: No. How would you go about doing that for a PL/SQL Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Oracle 11g performs that optimization for you.

That feature was added in 10g.  See page 60 of the presentation ["PL/SQL Performance - Debunking the Myths"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/plsql-performance-debunking-the-myt-131194.zip).  It includes an example very similar to your code.  The manual optimization was almost twice as fast in 9iR2, but does not help at all in 10gR1.

Although I can't tell you how Oracle does it.  As far as I know, that level of detail about how Oracle works does not exist.